# How to view this missing toolbar/window in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, toolbar

[image]The space at the top in android studio where recently opened java and xml files(I have marked that in my image) are shown has disappeared in my MacBook. How to bring it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top toolbar Window> Editor Tabs > Tabs Placement > Top.

that's should fix it.